# Internet Explorer: How to continuously (on the fly) pick which program to use when opening files?

Tags: internet-explorer, file-association

Issue:

I want to be able to open one file extension with multiple different programs depending on my choosing. Specifically in Internet Explorer.

On Firefox and Opera this is standard, they offer a drop down menu to select a program.

I have tried to both de-associate the file type and remove the association all together, it has not done anything.

I am using IE8 I'm not sure if this has been changed in 9 or 10.

My specific situation:

I currently store all my .dwg (CAD files) on SharePoint. When I click on one of the files I get the "open" "save" option, but the open button is already defaulted to AutoCAD. now sometimes I want to open it in DesignReview because I want to mark it up. I don't want to be actually saving the files onto my desktop just so I can mark them up. Firefox has a drop down bar from which you can chose programs, I need this for Internet Explorer.

Does it exist? Maybe a plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you delete the file type association under Control Panel > Folder options it will prompt what you want to do with the file every time, then uncheck the "always open with this application" option on the bottom of the open with dialog.

Comment: Yah i did try that, i even tryed to remove the association all together it doesn't give options, same prompt as always :/